# Shell Script is not generating the logs file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I am trying to capture the netstat command logs for every minute.I have written a script which runs in loop.But my script executes till **capturing logs** statement into test.sh code.

**test.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
export TODAY=`date`
export i=0
while [ true ]
do
echo "capturing logs" $i
    sh test1.sh > test$i.log
echo "sleeping for 1m"    
sleep 60
i=$((i+1))
done
```

**test1.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
netstat -l 5575 | while IFS= read -r line; do printf '[%s] %s\n' "$(date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')" "$line"; done
```

The output from above script is :
capturing logs

(If i press crtl-c then it move further and it display "sleeping for 1m" statement and i need to press again crtl-c when it comes to "capturing logs statement").

Comment: How long did you wait until you press CTRL+C? Maybe your output of netstat -l 5575 is taking too long?

Comment: No netstat output is very short.

Answer (score 0):

```
sh test1.sh > test$i.log
```

Is waiting for test1.sh to finish, which probably takes way too long to complete.

Try to execute test1.sh in another tty like

```
setsid sh -c 'exec [launch the script] <> /dev/tty[number_of_tty] >&0 2>&1'
```

and let me know.

Be careful not to run a lot of processes on the same tty. You can play with [number_of_tty] to avoid this.

Could solve the problem, could not, but it's worth trying.

Comment: can i use any number for number_of_tty.                                                               setsid sh -c 'exec  test1.sh <> /dev/tty01  >&0 2>&1'

Comment: depends on how many ttys do u have. Distro?
Btw, the more tty u use, the more resource you use. I had 64 ttys at once and had high cpu load (each one with a loop script) so be careful, tough the sleep step surely help to avoid overloads.

It isnt an elegant solution, but could work. Try to implement a tty check for seeing if it's free.
I also suggest debugging netstat to see how much time it takes to complete.